# Not able to upgrade to iOS 12 from iOS12 Beta

Tags: ios, upgrade, beta

[image]

Every 2 seconds I’m getting the notification above

But when I go to the Software updates’ tab it says: Your software is up to date

[image]

**iOS Version:** 12.0 (16A5365b)
**Model:** iPhone 6Plus (64GB) NGAH2HN/A

Comment: You don't say what you have done to try and fix this, which beta are you using (Public or Developer), which version of the beta, or which model of iPhone you are using. Have you tried force rebooting the phone? The procedure varies from phone to phone (iPhone 7 is different from iPhone 8 and iPhone X). Have you tried resetting network or other settings? You may be stuck unless you install the current non-beta version iOS. You may want to check out <https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask> to see what else may be missing from your question.

Comment: @mark is totally correct in general, this is a special case since it’s easily triggered a dozen times in 10 minutes and clearly a time calculation bug.  The one piece of information that would make this super useful is for tsumit  to include the build version of which this issue is occurring.

Comment: Whoa! Liked the kind of support I am getting here! Made some edits to the question with details

Comment: @Mark I am using Public beta and recently upgraded to beta 9. But it seems after the upgrade, my beta doesn't look like the beta anymore, at least it is not mentioned in the system information.Gone through the links you've shared and seems I need to switch to non-beta first.

Answer (score 4):

This is an Apple bug that looks like it is fairly wide spread.

[Apparent iOS 12 beta bug causes never-ending notifications to update software](https://appleinsider.com/articles/18/08/30/apparent-ios-12-beta-bug-causes-never-ending-notifications-to-update-software)

Answer (score 3):

Apple has provided a fix as of today. (2018-8-31)

iOS 12 public beta 10 (build 16A5366a or newer should do the trick)

https://apple.news/AwGLjBb1sSwivkwnb3d7-VA

Comment: Dang, @bjbk beat me to it. I was hoping to update my answer today, but I was busy when the news broke.

Answer (score 1):

Change the date back a day or three (or more as time marches in) and that will temporarily prevent the dialog.

Comment: Moving the date back can break a lot of other things, but you are correct a date calculation triggers this excessively.